# brew install gfortran Error: You must `brew link gmp' before gfortran can be installed

Tags: hyperlink, homebrew, gfortran, gmp, pythonbrew

I tried installing gfortran using homebrew before I needed to install pythonbrew. I need pythonbrew to install and use the misopy package on my iMac. I keep getting this error when I want to install gfortran:

```
> brew install gfortran
Error: You must `brew link gmp' before gfortran can be installed
```

I tried reinstalling gmp using homebrew in mac and this did not help. Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. I did not completely remove the swig/gfortran/libpng files and their dependecies. If this information helps others installing pythonbrew and python 2.7 in mac.

I followed this guys instruction to start with in first place:

https://gist.github.com/audy/4012573

Do not mind his swearing I can understand where that comes from! :-)

KR